# Java animation freeze

Tags: java, animation, jframe, jpanel, refresh

I am trying to write a simple 2d animation engine in Java for visualizing later programming projects. However, I am having problems with the window refresh. On running, the frame will sometimes display a blank panel instead of the desired image. This begins with a few frames at a time at apparently random intervals, worsening as the program continues to run until the actual image only occasionally blinks into view. The code for processing each frame is run, but nothing in the frame is actually displayed. I believe the problem may come from my computer more than my code (certainly not from bad specs though), but am not sure. Help much appreciated.

Three classes. Code here:

```
package animator;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.applet.AudioClip;

public class APanel extends JPanel
{

    public APanel(int l, int h){

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(l,h));
        setLocation(80, 80);
        setVisible(true);
        setFocusable(true);     

    }

    public Graphics renderFrame(Graphics g){

        return g;

    }   

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        requestFocusInWindow();
        renderFrame(g);

    }

}
```

---

```
package animator;

import java.awt.*;

public class Animator extends APanel
//extending the APanel class allows you to code for different animations
//while leaving the basic functional animator untouched
{

    public static final int SCREEN_X = 700;
    public static final int SCREEN_Y = 700;

    int frameNum;

    public Animator() {
        super(SCREEN_X, SCREEN_Y);
        frameNum = 0;
    }

    public Graphics renderFrame(Graphics g) {

        frameNum++;
        g.drawString(""+frameNum,5,12);
        return g;

    }

}
```

---

```
package animator;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Runner {

   int framerate = 30;
    Animator a = new Animator();
    JFrame j = new JFrame();

    public Runner(){
        j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        j.add(a);
        start();
        j.setSize(a.getPreferredSize());
        j.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void start() {
        Timer t = new Timer(1000/framerate, new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                j.getComponent(0).paint(j.getComponent(0).getGraphics());

                //The following line of code keeps the window locked to a preferred size
//                j.setSize(j.getComponent(0).getPreferredSize());
            }

        });
        t.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Runner r = new Runner();
    }

}
```

Comment: Never do `j.getComponent(0).paint(j.getComponent(0).getGraphics());` when trying to paint to the screen! Instead, simply call `repaint` on the component you want updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some serious mistakes in your code which could be the cause or a factor of your problem...

- `j.setSize(a.getPreferredSize());` is irrelevant, simply use `JFrame#pack`, you get better results as it takes into account the frame decorations
- `j.setSize(j.getComponent(0).getPreferredSize());` use `JFrame#setResizable` and pass it `false` instead...
- NEVER do `j.getComponent(0).paint(j.getComponent(0).getGraphics());` this!  You are not responsible for the painting of components within Swing, that's the decision of the `RepaintManager`.  Just call `j.repaint()`
- `super(SCREEN_X, SCREEN_Y);`...just override the `getPreferredSize` method and return the size you want.
- `setLocation(80, 80);` irrelevant, as the component is under the control of a layout manager
- `setVisible(true);` (inside `APanel`)...Swing components are already visible by default, with the exception of windows and `JInternalFrame`s

And finally...

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    requestFocusInWindow();
    renderFrame(g);
}
```

There is never any need for this method to be made `public`, you NEVER want someone to be able to call it, this will break the paint chain and could have serious ramifications in the ability for the component to paint itself properly.

You MUST call `super.paintComponent` before performing any custom painting, otherwise you could end up with all sorts of wonderful paint artifacts and issues

Never modify the state of a component from within a `paint` method...while it "might" not be an immediate issue calling `requestFocusInWindow();` within your `paintComponent` could have side effects you don't know about...

Instead, it should look more like...

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    renderFrame(g);
}
```

Comment: I've implemented your improvements (thanks!) and the problem has been solved on Windows--it was due to using paint() instead of repaint(). However, I like working on Linux and the animation slows down in Linux unless the mouse is moving over the animation's window or the window is being moved. The freeze displays the last frame rendered, not a blank frame. I'd greatly appreciate any advice for fixing this. If it's relevant, I'm using Mint with Cinnamon as my desktop manager.